# Connecting a Sensirion SPS30 PM sensor to RPi

Tags: sensor, connection, connectors

I am trying to connect the [Sensirion SPS30](https://www.sensirion.com/en/environmental-sensors/particulate-matter-sensors-pm25/)

I'm having trouble connecting it to my breadboard.

This is the connection on the sensor.

[image: This is the connection for the sensor]

I am thinking that I need a 5 pin JST / Molex to plug into the sensor and a breakout board like this one (but with a 5 pin connection) to connect the cable to the breadboard

[image: breakout board]

My problem is I can't find either for sale or that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Does anyone know how to connect this to the RPi??

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for: [SparkFun's Breadboard to JST-ZHR Cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15108)

As a bonus, SparkFun sells the [SPS30 with the breakout cable for $47](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15103) - about HALF the price it goes for on Digikey (without the breakout cable)